# Небольшие правки на странице ивентов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, знаки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

1. > Чтобы получить знак «Не робот» познакомьтесь с сотрудником Stack
   >   Overflow на событие, которое организовано Stack Overflow или при
   >   поддержке Stack Overflow, в котором принимает участие 50 и более
   >   человек.

   1. Пропущена запятая после **«Не робот»**.
   2. В **событие** должно быть окончании **ии**.
2. > На данный момент, у нас нет планов.

Запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В траде: https://ru.traducir.win/string/5928
2. Добавил в траде: https://ru.traducir.win/string/3304